# React/Redux: Why am I receiving this.props error in my Container?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I can't figure out why I'm receiving this error "TypeError: this.props.reviews.map is not a function" for my ReviewsContainer file.

I feel like I'm missing something, but I believe I defined my props in the Reviews component.

I have a Reviews component, here:

```
/components/reviews/Reviews.js


import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const ReviewCard = props => {
  const url = `/reviews/${props.review.id}`;
  return (
    <div className="ReviewCard">
      <NavLink to={url} exact>
        <p>
          <strong>Title:</strong> {props.review.title}
        </p>
      </NavLink>

      <p>
        <strong>Content: </strong>
        {props.review.content}
      </p>
      <img className="ReviewImage" src={props.review.img_url} alt="(no pic)" />

    </div>
  );
};

export default ReviewCard;
```

My fetch action file:

```
/actions/reviewsFetch.js

export const reviewsFetch = () => {

    return dispatch => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/reviews', {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(reviews => dispatch ({
            type: 'REVIEWS_FETCH',
            payload: reviews.data
        }))
    }
}
```

and finally, my ReviewsContainer file:

```
/containers/ReviewsContainer.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { reviewsFetch } from "../actions/reviewsFetch";
import ReviewCard from "../components/reviews/Reviews";


class ReviewsContainer extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.reviewsFetch();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.reviews.map((review, index) => (
          <ReviewCard review={review} key={index} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    reviews: state.reviews
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { reviewsFetch }
)(ReviewsContainer);
```

Reviews Reducer

```
export default function reviewReducer (state = {reviews: [], comments: []}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REVIEWS_FETCH':
            return {...state, reviews: action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css';
import App from './App.js';
import store from './store.js';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ store }>
      <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import reviews from './reducers/reviewReducer'

const reducers = combineReducers({
    reviews
  })
  
  const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
  const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)))

  export default store
```

Comment: This error tells you that `reviews` **is** defined, but is not an array. Please include your reducer so we can see how `reviews` is getting set.

Comment: @BrianThompson I added the reducer at the end

Comment: Ok where do you configure your store? That has an effect on the nested structure. Since `state.reviews` is not defined (and appears to be an object), I'm guessing your configure store names the reducer `reviews` meaning you would need to access it as `state.reviews.reviews`.

Comment: It's configured in my index.js file, i think (i'm super new to this). I added my index and store at the end too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few sources of confusion here, but the simple answer is to change the `mapStateToProps` function like this:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    // reviews: state.reviews
    reviews: state.reviews.reviews
  };
};
```

### Here's why

State is an object. That object can correspond to a single reducer, or it can be nested to include other objects, arrays, etc. These nested objects typically correspond to other reducer functions. All these reducers get fused into a single state object by `combineReducers`.

Your store (redux state) has been created as the following:

```js
import reviews from './reducers/reviewReducer'

const reducers = combineReducers({
  reviews
})
```

The import statement is important because even though your reducer is named `reviewReducer` it is exported as default and imported as `reviews`. That in addition to the `combineReducers` function call (as opposed to just using a single reducer) will result in a state object looking like this:

```js
state: {
  reviews: {
    reviews: [], 
    comments: []
  }
}
```

This means, to access the array like you want, you need to use `state.reviews.reviews` (@heshiebee was on the right track). This naming is up to you. For example, you could alter it like this:

```js
const reducers = combineReducers({
  myNestedState: reviews
})
```

Then you'd access it like `state.myNestedState.reviews`.

Comment: amazing, thank you so much! such a good explanation, i really appreciate this

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your missing the Redux reducer name.

So whatever your reducer name is you would do `state.[reducer name].reviews`.

This is based on the assumption that

1. Your reducers are nested and not on the root store.
2. You defined `reviews` as an empty array in your reducer.

Comment: It's possible, but its also possible that they only have one reducer and `state` is a single unnested object.

Comment: So i added state.reviewReducer.reviews and i'm now getting an error that says cannot read property 'reviews' of undefined, and reviews is an empty array in my reducer (i added my reducer file at the end, above)

Comment: Did you import your reducer in index.js? post your index.js code.

Answer (score 0):

At the time your `ReviewsContainer` component is mounted `this.props.reviews` may not have been populated as an array, try adding a check first to ensure that `this.props.reviews` is already populated as an array before trying to map over it like this

```
{this.props.reviews.length && this.props.reviews.map((review, index) => (
```

Comment: This won't help since the error says `map` is not a function. If `reviews` was not defined (falsy) it would say "cannot access property map of undefined" or "null" etc.

Comment: @Brian Thompson Updated my answer.

Comment: With the update, this would be enough to prevent the error, but there is almost certainly another bug here that is the true problem. If the datatype of `reviews` is changing (seems like from an object to array), it's either not intentional or a really bad practice. That's really the problem the OP needs to solve.