# What should be the name of state parameter while fetching data from redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a react application with redux. I am confused on how I should access the data in my redux state, like `store.Like`?

In my component, I am using `mapStateToProps`. What should be after `state.` in order to access the data?

```js
const mapStateToProps=state=>({
  data:state.cardItems
})
```

What should be after state._____ (in place of `cardItems`)in order to assign state data to data.

Here is how I combine the reducers:

```js
export default combineReducers({
    cardItems,
})
```

You can check my app [here](https://github.com/anil-sidhu/redux-tut).

Thanks

Comment: It's entirely dependent on the shape of your reducer(s) and how you combine them if there are more than one.

Comment: I just have 1 reducer.what should it be then? and how do I check it in case of multiple reducers?

Comment: It might be more helpful if you include what is going wrong with your current attempt? Does `state.cardItems` not do what you expect, throw an error, etc?

Comment: its working but how this name is being decided?I want to know that

Comment: It's being decided when you `combineReducers` here: `export default combineReducers({cardItems})`. You are passing in an object with a key called `cardItems` and a value of that reducer's state.

Comment: There might be a better answer/explanation out there, but the "Here's Why" section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64707492/9381601) addresses how a Redux state takes its shape.

Comment: Also to add upon: If you export the reducer as `export default combineReducers({myFavName: cardItems})`, then you can access them inside the `mapStateToProps` as `state.myFavName`.

Answer (score 1):

Assign your initialState to state in reducer.